Почему Cloudflare подгружает старые DNS записи?
Перенес сайт на новый хостинг.
Удалил его предварительно из Cloudflare.
После переезда на новый хостинг снова добавляю сайт на Cloudflare, но он импортирует старые DNS записи.
Добавляет старые записи хостинга beget.
Как сделать, чтобы Cloudflare подгрузил записи нового хостинга?

Что значит «подгрузил»? По логике, это наоборот вы сами должны загрузить в Cloudflare те записи, которые вам нужны

72 часа после смены NS серверов прошло? Если нет, то вам нужно у себя на ПК, или на телефоне, установить DNS 1.1.1.1 1.0.0.1, а на других ждать.

при добавлении сайта cloudflare рекомендует автоматически считать записи.
